# Problems installing ROS1 Packages

Tags: ros-melodic, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm normaly working with ROS2, so probably my Problems originate from not having that much experience with ROS in general and especially not with ROS1, but I have a [package](https://github.com/FieldRobotEvent/virtual_maize_field) that's only provided in ROS1 but that I need for generating some worlds. Hover, I really struggle to install it.

**What I tried**

First thing I tried was just running

```
rosdep install virtual_maize_field
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required
resources to answer your query
Missing resource virtual_maize_field
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

Next, I tried cloning the Repository and then trying to install it with `rosdep` via the path:

```
git clone https://github.com/FieldRobotEvent/virtual_maize_field.git
rosdep install --from-path virtual_maize_field
```

This resulted in a lot of packages being installed, but when I tried to run a script, I just got the response that the package could not be found.

```
[rospack] Error: package 'virtual_maize_field' not found
```

After that, I tried following [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/240235/how-to-install-packages-from-github/) article, but that got me the same result as before; the package couldn't be found :/

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400594/problems-installing-ros1-packages/) by [isiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/102220/isiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your linked repository seems to have a `ros2` branch there: https://github.com/FieldRobotEvent/virtual_maize_field/tree/ros2

Did you try it?

The code seems to be mostly non-ROS specific to be honest, it can be ported to ROS2.

Did you build it with `catkin make`? `rosdep` is for dependency packages

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/102220/isiko/) on 2022-05-14**:
Thanks, didn't even realize that :D